# Lasso-ing the order of a lag?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, regularization

Suppose I have longitudinal data  of the form $\mathbf Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_J) \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$ (I have multiple observations, this is just the form of a single one). I'm interested in restrictions on $\Sigma$. An unrestricted $\Sigma$ is equivalent to taking
$$
Y_j = \alpha_j + \sum_{\ell = 1} ^ {j - 1} \phi_{\ell j} Y_{j-\ell} + \varepsilon_j
$$
with $\varepsilon_j \sim N(0, \sigma_j)$.

This is typically not done since it requires estimating $O(J^2)$ covariance parameters. A model is "lag-$k$" if we take
$$
Y_j = \alpha_j + \sum_{\ell = 1} ^ k \phi_{\ell j} Y_{j - \ell} + \varepsilon_j,
$$
i.e. we only use the preceding $k$ terms to predict $Y_j$ from the history.

What I'd really like to do is use some kind of shrinkage idea to zero out some of the $\phi_{\ell j}$, like the LASSO. But the thing is, I also would like the method I use to prefer models which are lag-$k$ for some $k$; I'd like to penalize higher order lags more than lower order lags. I think this is something we would particularly like to do given that the predictors are highly correlated.

An additional issue is that if (say) $\phi_{35}$ is shrunk to $0$ I would also like it if $\phi_{36}$ is shrunk to $0$, i.e. the same lag is used in all of the conditional distributions.

I could speculate on this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there any LASSO techniques designed to get at this sort of problem? Am I better off just doing something else entirely, like stepwise inclusion of lag orders? Since my model space is small, I could even use an $L_0$ penalty on this problem I guess?

Answer (score 2):

The [ordered LASSO](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6447.pdf) seems to be what you're looking for: It computes the regularized regression coefficients $\beta_{1...j}$ as in the standard LASSO, but subject to the additional constraint that $|\beta_1| \geq |\beta_2|...\geq|\beta_j|$.

This accomplishes the second goal of zeroing out coefficients for higher-order lags, but is more restrictive than the sole restriction of preferring a lower lag model. And as others point out, this is a heavy restriction that can be very difficult to justify.

Having dispensed with the caveats, the paper presents the method's results on both real and simulated time series data, and details algorithms to find the coefficients. The conclusion mentions an R package, but the paper is rather recent and a search on CRAN for "ordered LASSO" comes up empty, so I suspect the package is still in development.

The paper also offers a generalized approach in which two regularization parameters "encourage near-monotonicity." (See p. 6.) In other words, one should be able to tune the parameters to allow for a relaxed ordering. Sadly, neither examples nor comparisons of the relaxed method are provided. But, the authors write that implementing this change is a simple matter of replacing one algorithm with another, so one hopes it will be part of the coming R package.

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting that this is a recent idea. I actually came up with the same idea discussing the problem with a friend back when I asked the question 9 months ago, but never investigated it in depth! I just assumed that the idea wasn't that novel, or that someone else had written a paper about it already.

Comment: Quite welcome! I was surprised that it was so recent myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do cross validation repeatedly from k = 0 to whatever the maximum is, and plot the performance against k. Since the model is being tested on data it hasn't seen before, there is no guarantee the complex models will perform better, and indeed you should see a degradation in performance if the model becomes too complex due to overfitting. Personally I think this is safer and easier to justify than having an arbitrary penalty factor, but your mileage may vary.

I also don't really follow how ordered Lasso answers the question. It seems too restrictive, it is completely forcing the ordering of the coefficients. Whereas the original question may end up for some data having a solution where $\phi_{lj}$ is not strictly decreasing with l.

Comment: To add LaTeX to your question, enclose the expression between dollar signs ($).

Comment: (1) From the model alone, it isn't obvious that the coefficient ordering is desirable, but *substantively* it is reasonable. In a repeated measures clinical trial, for example, there is no substantive reason to expect that a small perturbation of $Y_{j-2}$ to stochastically influence $Y_j$ more than a small perturbation of $Y_{j-1}$. The ordered LASSO makes better use of this a priori knowledge, with the minor risk that it might be not be true.

Comment: (2) Generally, I wouldn't use this CV strategy at least partially because it is too dogmatic. I can get better predictions by judiciously shrinking a lag, rather than throwing it out entirely.

Comment: Nir, a useful comment on the ordered LASSO. I've edited my answer to be a bit more comprehensive. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sean. Guy, I don't think it is too dogmatic. You are not setting a k in stone, but rather allowing it to vary. The k it chooses will be at the onset of overfitting. 
I also strongly disagree with your statement of supposed a priori knowledge. Something seeming reasonable and knowing that thing are completely different.
I must admit there seems to be a resistance in traditional stats to cross validation I've never understood. I'd choose predictive efficiency on out of sample data over adding assumptions any day.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy choosing a tuning parameter, or choosing between stratgies via CV; my problem is with the discrete model choice. Your approach is dogmatic in the sense that it either provides *no* regularization to a given coefficient, or *completely zeros it out*. There is nothing in between. There is reason to expect estimators with this property to not perform as well from a predictive standpoint as comparable methods which provide soft shrinkage (i.e. ones which differentially penalize the lags to make it equivalent to choosing the lag order by CV).

Comment: WRT my supposed a priori knowledge - I agree, but I am very confident that if we applied the ordered-LASSO to many identical clinical trials and compared to results from a non-ordered LASSO we would get better results from the ordered. Picking between the two by CV would do better than both, but that is beside the point...

Comment: I guess you don't need to be very confident, you can just test the two approaches using cross validation and see which gives better results :-). 

Another approach which I still think is much better than ordered lasso is to choose a penalty form, e.g. have a different prefactor on each lasso penalty term that is exponentially decaying. Than cross validate to find the best exponential constant.

Comment: In summary: if your goal is strictly prediction, then you are better off using something less restrictive with hyperparameters you can optimize over to select the best model.

If your goal is inference, then an overly restrictive models makes any supposed inferences questionable.

Either way I just don't see an advantage to ordered LASSO unless the ordering represented definite knowledge. I'm quite confident you can find a better predictive model without that constraint.

Comment: Also, what I thought was clear in this convo, but maybe isn't: it's usually useful in time series analysis to limit how far back your model goes for many reasons. If nothing else, by going back a finite lag, you at least know the dimension of the space in which you're fitting. With no limit on how far back you go, your dimension increases as your datasets get longer.

Comment: WRT the time series aspect - this isn't a time series problem per se. The problem is a clinical trial in a regulatory setting, with $J$ fixed and often small (e.g. $J = 6$ in this particular problem), and there aren't very many replicates, maybe $100$.

Comment: Is there any heuristic for why an exponential decay is a reasonable choice? This sort of penalty does seem reasonable.

Comment: Another motivation for some sort of ordering constraint as opposed to (say) using an unaltered LASSO - the $Y_j$ are clearly highly correlated, so without some sort of constraint on the ordering - whether a hard ordering or something else - an unaltered LASSO might zero out some of the recent terms simply due to noise in the data.

Comment: Ah I see, the way you phrased your problem I definitely thought that J was much larger, my apologies. If J is small and in particular anticipated to be fixed in the future, that does change my perspective. A lot of my concerns with finding a hard cut-off have to do with a time-series mentality wherein data can be arbitrary long (and not always the same length).

Answer (score 1):

The nested LASSO penalty ([pdf](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~elevina/levina_zhu.pdf)) could be employed but there are no R packages for it.

Comment: At present, this is more of a comment than an answer. Can you expand it a little, perhaps by discussing the nested LASSO penalty, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I know you wrote it as a premise, but I would not use the ordered LASSO without being absolutely sure that this is thing that is needed, because the assumptions of the ordered LASSO are not directly appropriate for time-series prediction. As a counter-example, consider the case where you have a delay-time of, say, ten time-steps between measurement and target. Obviously, the ordered LASSO constraints cannot handle such a effects without attributing nonsense to the first nine parameters.

In contrast, I would rather stick to the normal LASSO and include *all* previous observation -- particularly because you wrote your model space is small, and coordinate-descent optimization routines for the LASSO (as described [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Fv33%2Fi01%2Fpaper&ei=80zeU-KuK9Db4QShloHAAw&usg=AFQjCNEHiTrirITAlESPVPCAh83ht4xLzg&sig2=N_iz1ua34eHgI3vrNJvpSQ&bvm=bv.72197243,d.bGE)) are working efficiently also for large datasets. Then compute the path for the regularization strength parameter $\lambda$ and look which parameters get included as you go from large $\lambda$ to $\lambda=0$. Especially those included earlier are the important ones.

Finally, you have to choose an appropriate criterion and optimize the parameter $\lambda$ using cross-validation, standard one-dimensional minimization or whatever. The criterion can for example be something as "prediction error + number of included variables" (--AIC criterion-like).

Comment: I would obviously not be interested in constraints on the order of the coefficients if I did not have strong *a priori* reasons to believe it. For the models that I suspect to be likely, heuristically the ordered LASSO should be more efficient. Having a lag-10 coefficient with the other 9 being 0 makes no sense in my *substantive* setting. This is a problem that my colleagues have worked on (ordered based shrinkage on the lags), but they used Bayesuan ideas and so wouldn't consider a (non-Bayesian) LASSO.

Comment: Ok, you seem to know what you do. But remember that the ordered LASSO is more strongly constrained than your "once zero - always zero" statement. Alternatively, you could also consider a model where the parameters enter in a multiplicative way. Then, the relative importance may either grow or decrease until a coefficient becomes zero.